# How to specify a NonSerialized field with public accessors for XML Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-3.5, xml-serialization, nonserializedattribute

How do you specify a NonSerialized field with public accessors for XML Serialization?

```
[NonSerialized]
public String _fooBar;
//Declaring the property here will serialize the _fooBar field
public String FooBar
{
    get { return _fooBar; }
    set { _fooBar = value; }
}
```

Comment: I assume this is a made up example? Otherwise you can just use an  auto property and mark that as `NonSerialized`.

Comment: The attribute cannot be applied to properties.

Comment: @BrokenGlass I actually get "Attribute 'NonSerialized' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations." on an auto-property...

Comment: Yes, Hans is right - my mistake.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - `[XmlIgnore]` works with auto-properties, though.

Comment: @MPelletier: Would have been good to know you are looking for *XML serialization* from the beginning - kudos to @Hans for catching it.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - I just, very naively, discovered that it made a difference. My bad.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved - and we both learnt something in the process ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Properties don't get serialized by `BinaryFormatter`, only fields.  The `[NonSerialized]` attribute has no meaning for XML serialization.  Use `[XmlIgnore]` instead.